# C# Getting an object's actual TypeDescriptionProvider or TypeDescriptor

Tags: c#

I realise that this is an unusual issue, but:

I have created a custom TypeDescriptionProvider that can store and return different `TypeDescriptors` based on the requested object Type. What I have noticed however is that regardless of the `TypeDescriptionProvider` associated with a Type (be-it custom or default) the `TypeDescriptor.GetProvider()` always returns an (internal class) `System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.TypeDescriptionNode` object (some kind of wrapper around the actual `TypeDescriptionProvider`). In turn calling `GetTypeDescriptor()` on this object always returns a `System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.TypeDescriptionNode.DefaultTypeDescriptor` object (another wrapper) and stranger still does not call the `TypeDescriptionProvider`'s actual `GetTypeDescriptor()` method.

Does this mean that there is really no way to get back either an object's actual `TypeDescriptionProvider` or its `TypeDescriptor` from its provider? The methods to return the classname, properties, etc. still work as expected on the `DefaultTypeDescriptor`, but I am unable to compare or find out if two objects use the same `TypeDescriptor` (which is what I need currently).

Does anyone know how to either get the actual `TypeDescriptionProvider`, or get the actual TypeDescriptor from the wrapped provider?

Thank you in advance.

Ex:

```
public class TestTypeDescriptionProvider : TypeDescriptionProvider
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, ICustomTypeDescriptor> _descriptors = new Dictionary<Type, ICustomTypeDescriptor>();

    ...static method to add to the cache...

    public override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(Type objectType, object instance)
    {
        if (objectType == null)
            return _descriptors[instance.GetType()];

        return _descriptors[objectType];
    }
}

...    

TypeDescriptionProvider p = TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(obj.GetType()); //p is a TypeDescriptionNode

ICustomTypeDescriptor td = p.GetTypeDescriptor(obj); // td is a DefaultTypeDescriptor
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at `TypeDescriptor.GetProvider` implementation using a tool such as .NET Reflector, you will see that the returned type is pretty hardcoded. It always returns a `TypeDescriptionNode`, like you observed. Same story for `GetTypeDescriptor`.

Now, what you could do is use Reflection mechanisms to get the actual `TypeDescriptionProvider` from `TypeDescriptionNode`. It's pretty easy, just get the private field named `Provider`, this is where the TypeDescriptionNode stores the actual implementation. Of course it's not supported, but I don't think this will change in a near future, and I don't really see a better way...

Comment: Thank you kindly for the reply. I was thinking about this option, but assumed that there should be a 'supported' method of accomplishing this. Since the TypeDescriptor system allows TypeDescriptors to be added at run-time, on a per Type or per object basis, this seems like a requirement that should come up fairly regularly - especially for PropertyGrid controls etc.

Comment: @ach - You can't determine what TypeDescriptor is actually at work behind the scene, but the behavior is the expected one. Ultimately, the system's DefaultTypeDescriptor ends up calling the configured one. PropertyGrids and other dynamic controls just get an ICustomTypeDescriptor, they don't care about the actual implementing type, they just care about the *behavior*, the contract that ICustomTypeDescriptor defines.

Comment: I do understand that the behavior you describe is the end goal here for most cases; however, if I was creating a PropertyGrid that can display multiple objects and types simultaneously (like in winforms), I wouldn't want to have to compare each object's propertyDescriptor set individually, but rather compare the TypeDescriptors.

Comment: If I had a collection of 200 unknown objects, some TypeA, some TypeB, and some TypeA with a custom TypeDescriptor, to find the common Properties (without comparing TypeDescriptors) I would have to compare the PropertyDecriptors of each object, a task that is an order of magnitude slower and more intensive.

Comment: @ach - ok, but, as a matter of fact, in the multiple selected objects case, the Winforms PropertyGrid for example, does not work like that, it just builds a hashtable/dictionary of all properties from all TypeDescriptors (wether they are custom or not), and displays them. I don't really see the need to "compare" property descriptors.

Comment: Since the grid displays the intersection of all propertyDescriptors, I don't think a simple hashtable would work. But even still, let's say that (in the example above) each object has 50 properties, and there are 200 objects. You would have to add 10,000 objects to the hashtable. If you could first compare the references of the TypeDescriptors, you would only have to add 600.

Comment: @ach - just take .NET Reflector and have a look at the SelectedObjects implementation. It's a hashtable.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if both types have the same `TypeDescriptionProviderAttribute`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but what I need to compare is the ICustomTypeDescriptor that the provider would return. I also want this to be generic enough that it would work even when the TypeDescriptionProvider is attached from code without the attribute.

Comment: I agree that I can write a comparer that looks at the individual properties of each ICustomTypeDescriptor, but this would be very slow. ClassName itself isn't guaranteed to be unique... There should be a way to do a referential comparison.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's no way at getting at the underlying provider directly other than by reflecting on private members.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and for looking into my issue. It seems strange that MS would put these limitations in place.